# Webcam color calibration using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, webcam

Having ordered half a dozen webcams online for a project I notice that the colors on the output are not consistent.

In order to compensate for this I have attempted to take a template image and extract the R,G and B histograms and tried to match the target images's RGB histograms based on this.

This was inspired from the description of the solution for a very similar problem [Comparative color calibration](http://www.matrox.com/imaging/en/products/software/mil/tools/color/)

The perfect solution will look like this :

[image]

In order to try to solve this I wrote the following script which performed poorly:

## EDIT (Thanks to @DanMašek and @api55)

```
import numpy as np

def show_image(title, image, width = 300):
    # resize the image to have a constant width, just to
    # make displaying the images take up less screen real
    # estate
    r = width / float(image.shape[1])
    dim = (width, int(image.shape[0] * r))
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # show the resized image
    cv2.imshow(title, resized)


def hist_match(source, template):
    """
    Adjust the pixel values of a grayscale image such that its histogram
    matches that of a target image

    Arguments:
    -----------
        source: np.ndarray
            Image to transform; the histogram is computed over the flattened
            array
        template: np.ndarray
            Template image; can have different dimensions to source
    Returns:
    -----------
        matched: np.ndarray
            The transformed output image
    """

    oldshape = source.shape
    source = source.ravel()
    template = template.ravel()

    # get the set of unique pixel values and their corresponding indices and
    # counts
    s_values, bin_idx, s_counts = np.unique(source, return_inverse=True,
                                            return_counts=True)
    t_values, t_counts = np.unique(template, return_counts=True)

    # take the cumsum of the counts and normalize by the number of pixels to
    # get the empirical cumulative distribution functions for the source and
    # template images (maps pixel value --> quantile)
    s_quantiles = np.cumsum(s_counts).astype(np.float64)
    s_quantiles /= s_quantiles[-1]
    t_quantiles = np.cumsum(t_counts).astype(np.float64)
    t_quantiles /= t_quantiles[-1]

    # interpolate linearly to find the pixel values in the template image
    # that correspond most closely to the quantiles in the source image
    interp_t_values = np.interp(s_quantiles, t_quantiles, t_values)

    return interp_t_values[bin_idx].reshape(oldshape)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import lena, ascent
import cv2

source = cv2.imread('/media/somadetect/Lexar/color_transfer_data/1/frame10.png')
s_b = source[:,:,0]
s_g = source[:,:,1]
s_r = source[:,:,2]
template =  cv2.imread('/media/somadetect/Lexar/color_transfer_data/5/frame6.png')
t_b = source[:,:,0]
t_r = source[:,:,1]
t_g = source[:,:,2]

matched_b = hist_match(s_b, t_b)
matched_g = hist_match(s_g, t_g)
matched_r = hist_match(s_r, t_r)

y,x,c = source.shape
transfer  = np.empty((y,x,c), dtype=np.uint8)

transfer[:,:,0] = matched_r
transfer[:,:,1] = matched_g
transfer[:,:,2] = matched_b

show_image("Template", template)
show_image("Target", source)
show_image("Transfer", transfer)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Template image :

[image]

Target Image:

[image]

The Matched Image:

[image]

Then I found Adrian's (pyimagesearch) attempt to solve a very similar problem in the following link

[Fast Color Transfer](https://github.com/jrosebr1/color_transfer)

The results seem to be fairly good with some saturation defects. I would welcome any suggestions or pointers on how to address this issue so all web cam outputs could be calibrated to output similar colors based on one template image.

Comment: While not knowing much about machine-vision, this color-transfer approach just don't seem right to me. It's a completely different task it's approaching. In your case, i suppose, you want something which has some underlying model, which explains why those cameras are behaving differently! Ignoring such a model might lead to too many degrees of freedom / not enough regularization and therefore bad results. Again, not much experience, but those cameras internally surely are not working with RGB, but probably some Bayer-pattern which allows a more tuned *noise-model* (sensor-data available?).

Comment: Did you order a dozen cameras of different brands, or are they different within the same brand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attempted a white patch based calibration routine. Here is the link https://theiszm.wordpress.com/tag/white-balance/.

The code snippet follows:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def hist_match(source, template):
    """
    Adjust the pixel values of a grayscale image such that its histogram
    matches that of a target image

    Arguments:
    -----------
        source: np.ndarray
            Image to transform; the histogram is computed over the flattened
            array
        template: np.ndarray
            Template image; can have different dimensions to source
    Returns:
    -----------
        matched: np.ndarray
            The transformed output image
    """

    oldshape = source.shape
    source = source.ravel()
    template = template.ravel()

    # get the set of unique pixel values and their corresponding indices and
    # counts
    s_values, bin_idx, s_counts = np.unique(source, return_inverse=True,
                                            return_counts=True)
    t_values, t_counts = np.unique(template, return_counts=True)

    # take the cumsum of the counts and normalize by the number of pixels to
    # get the empirical cumulative distribution functions for the source and
    # template images (maps pixel value --> quantile)
    s_quantiles = np.cumsum(s_counts).astype(np.float64)
    s_quantiles /= s_quantiles[-1]
    t_quantiles = np.cumsum(t_counts).astype(np.float64)
    t_quantiles /= t_quantiles[-1]

    # interpolate linearly to find the pixel values in the template image
    # that correspond most closely to the quantiles in the source image
    interp_t_values = np.interp(s_quantiles, t_quantiles, t_values)
    return interp_t_values[bin_idx].reshape(oldshape)

# Read original image
im_o = cv2.imread('/media/Lexar/color_transfer_data/5/frame10.png')
im = im_o
cv2.imshow('Org',im)
cv2.waitKey()

B = im[:,:, 0]
G = im[:,:, 1]
R = im[:,:, 2]

R= np.array(R).astype('float')
G= np.array(G).astype('float')
B= np.array(B).astype('float')

# Extract pixels that correspond to pure white R = 255,G = 255,B = 255
B_white = R[168, 351]
G_white = G[168, 351]
R_white = B[168, 351]

print B_white
print G_white
print R_white

# Compensate for the bias using normalization statistics
R_balanced = R / R_white
G_balanced = G / G_white
B_balanced = B / B_white

R_balanced[np.where(R_balanced > 1)] = 1
G_balanced[np.where(G_balanced > 1)] = 1
B_balanced[np.where(B_balanced > 1)] = 1

B_balanced=B_balanced * 255
G_balanced=G_balanced * 255
R_balanced=R_balanced * 255

B_balanced= np.array(B_balanced).astype('uint8')
G_balanced= np.array(G_balanced).astype('uint8')
R_balanced= np.array(R_balanced).astype('uint8')

im[:,:, 0] = (B_balanced)
im[:,:, 1] = (G_balanced)
im[:,:, 2] = (R_balanced)

# Notice saturation artifacts 
cv2.imshow('frame',im)
cv2.waitKey()

# Extract the Y plane in original image and match it to the transformed image 
im_o = cv2.cvtColor(im_o, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
im_o_Y = im_o[:,:,0]

im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
im_Y = im[:,:,0]

matched_y = hist_match(im_o_Y, im_Y)
matched_y= np.array(matched_y).astype('uint8')
im[:,:,0] = matched_y

im_final = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('frame',im_final)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The input image is:

[image]

The result of the script is:

[image]

Thank you all for suggestions and pointers!!

Answer (score 1):

Your script performs poorly because you are using the wrong index.

OpenCV images are BGR, so this was correct in your code:

```
source = cv2.imread('/media/somadetect/Lexar/color_transfer_data/1/frame10.png')
s_b = source[:,:,0]
s_g = source[:,:,1]
s_r = source[:,:,2]
template =  cv2.imread('/media/somadetect/Lexar/color_transfer_data/5/frame6.png')
t_b = source[:,:,0]
t_r = source[:,:,1]
t_g = source[:,:,2]
```

but this is wrong

```
transfer[:,:,0] = matched_r
transfer[:,:,1] = matched_g
transfer[:,:,2] = matched_b
```

since here you are using RGB and not BGR, so the color changes and your OpenCV still thinks it is BGR. That is why it looks weird.

It should be:

```
transfer[:,:,0] = matched_b
transfer[:,:,1] = matched_g
transfer[:,:,2] = matched_r
```

As other possible solutions, you may try to look which parameters can be set in your camera. Sometimes they have some auto parameters which you can set manually for all of them to match. Also, beware of this auto parameters, usually white balance and focus and others are set auto and they may change quite a lot in the same camera from one time to another (depending on illumination, etc etc).

## UPDATE:

As **DanMašek** points out, also

```
t_b = source[:,:,0]
t_r = source[:,:,1]
t_g = source[:,:,2]
```

is wrong, since the r should be index 2 and g index 1

```
t_b = source[:,:,0]
t_g = source[:,:,1]
t_r = source[:,:,2]
```

Comment: IMHO even the first part is not correct -- notice how `t_r` and `t_g` are swapped.

Comment: @DanMašek True, I didn't notice it, no wonder it does not work... all the channels where mixed

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my sloppy mistake with indices  @api55 I certainly need more caffeine. However It doesn't seem to solve my issue with template based color calibration yet.

Comment: @BharathS at least the algorithm seems to do what it is suppose to do :) the target looks almost like the matched

Comment: @api55 true. I am trying to match the target image to resemble the template. However i am getting very close to a solution will update this post soon.